# What are the meanings of the numbers "4500" written under the VOR and NDB boxes? (MHA?) (Recommended crossing altitude?)

Tags: ils, holding, jeppesen, symbology

Does it directly mean the minimum altitude for holdings on VOR or NDB or can it be interpreted in another way? Because MHA 4500 information for the holding is given on the right side. This picture is taken from LTBR airport's ILS Z or LOC Z Rwy 25R Jeppesen chart with page number 11-1.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying this is not in the Jeppesen documentation?

Comment: I didn't mention anything like that in the question. I'm also looking at the Jeppesen manual, but I couldn't see a one-to-one correspondence and wanted to ask this question because I felt the need to get approval for an equivalent explanation.

Comment: What’s the date on that chart?

Comment: 27 May 2022 is the revision date of the chart.

Comment: Could you post the entire chart rather than just a crop of the bit you're asking about

Comment: I'm taking a screenshot because the image quality is degraded in the full screen and the important part is too small. Also, if I can, I will share the link of the high resolution version of the page, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is a Crossing Altitude for the initial approach course / racetrack.

> Altitude/FL indicated by state source as recommended will be charted without over-bar and under-bars.

The MHA, on the other hand, is part of the missed approach procedure.

Comment: Does it always represent the intermediate approach course?

Comment: @pilot162 Are you asking about something other than the ILS Z as charted?  It is certainly possible to have other procedures or airways associated with the VOR, but the Crossing Altitude for the ILS Z procedure wouldn't be relevant to other uses.

Comment: Adjusted to initial course, not intermediate.

Comment: Let me summarize if I got it right. "4500" means the recommended VOR crossing altitude for performing the ILS procedure. Am I right?

Comment: @pilot162 Yes it is as simple as that.  If there is any lingering question about the procedure, it would be necessary to use the government chart or text rather than Jeppessen.